# Bs4: Trying to loop in diferent arrays with diferent lenghts. Get IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

With Beautifulsoup4 and python3.7 I'm trying to loop some arrays with links. After, want to get some text from tags. But I'm encountering and error passing the code on the terminal.

Here the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import csv
my_url = "http://www.example.com"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
links = page_soup.select('dt > a[href]')
link = [tag.get('href') for tag in links]
i = 0
for i in range(0, 5000):
    url = link[i]
    Client = uReq(url)
    pageHtml = Client.read()
    Client.close()  
    pSoup = soup(pageHtml, "html.parser")
    linkeas = pSoup.findAll(href=re.compile(my_url))
    def linkas(href):
        return href and re.compile("html").search(href) and re.compile(my_url).search(href)
    linka = pSoup.findAll(href=linkas)
    if linka != []:
    linkia = [tag.get('href') for tag in linka]
    linko = len(linkia)
    j = 0
    for j in range (0, linko):
        curl = linkia[j]
        cClient = uReq(curl)
        pageHtml = cClient.read()
        cClient.close() 
        Soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
        country = Soup.select('.class > a:nth-of-type(3)')
        countri = country[0].text.strip()
        print(countri)
```

I've tried for days several ways but got so far as this with no results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 22, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could someone give some tip?

NOTE:

Arrays show like this:

```
print(linkia)

['http://www.example/example/1.html']
['http://www.example/example/2.html']
['http://www.example/example/3.html', 'http://www.example/example/4.html', 
'http://www.example/example/5.html', 'http://www.example/example/6.html', 
'http://www.example/example/7.html', 'http://www.example/example/8.html', 
'http://www.example/example/9.html', 'http://www.example/example/10.html', 
'http://www.example/example/11.html', 'http://www.example/example/12.html', 
'http://www.example/example/13.html', 'http://www.example/example/14.html', 
'http://www.example/example/15.html', 'http://www.example/example/16.html', 
'http://www.example/example/17.html', 'http://www.example/example/18.html', 
'http://www.example/example/19.html']
['http://www.example/example/20.html', 'http://www.example/example/example/21.html', 
'http://www.example/example/example/22.html']
['http://www.example/example/23.html']
```

Thanks a lot for your time. Really appreciate. Will be connected all time with fast response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
i = 0
for i in range(0, 5000):
    url = link[i]
```

to just:

```
for url in link:
```

And then can get rid of the `url = link[i]`

You're essentially telling it to loop through 5000 items in your list, when you don't have 5000 items, hence the `list index out of range`. You really just want it to loop through each element until it runs out of items. And you can do that by simply saying `for url in link:`

Then the same for your other nested for loop.

change:

```
j = 0
for j in range (0, linko):
    curl = linkia[j]
```

to:

```
for curl in linkia:
```

I will also note that if you were to set it up the way you have it, you wouldn't need to set the initial i or j to be = 0. Since you set the range/list to go from 0, 5000...the for loop would automatically start at that first element of 0. But again, that point is irrelevant, as I would not recommend iterating through your list like that. It a) isn't robust (you would need exactly 5000 items in your list every time it gets to that loop), and b) while it would work ok for your second loop because you set the range from 0, to the length of the list, it really is unnecessary since you can condense that into 1 line.

Try:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import csv
my_url = "http://www.example.com"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
links = page_soup.select('dt > a[href]')
link = [tag.get('href') for tag in links]

for url in link:

    Client = uReq(url)
    pageHtml = Client.read()
    Client.close()  
    pSoup = soup(pageHtml, "html.parser")
    linkeas = pSoup.findAll(href=re.compile(my_url))
    def linkas(href):
        return href and re.compile("html").search(href) and re.compile(my_url).search(href)
    linka = pSoup.findAll(href=linkas)
    if linka != []:
        linkia = [tag.get('href') for tag in linka]

        for curl in linkia:

            cClient = uReq(curl)
            pageHtml = cClient.read()
            cClient.close() 
            Soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
            country = Soup.select('.class > a:nth-of-type(3)')
            countri = country[0].text.strip()
            print(countri)
```

Comment: Ou! That looks beautiful. Anyway have tried and get: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 18, in <module> IndexError: list index out of range` What I'm missing?Oh, And byt the way, Thanks a lot for your time. Your response and explanation is really great!

Comment: is it possible to share the exact url you're using? so I can plug it in and see what I get

Comment: Can I send it to you private?

Comment: The first loop seems to work. Not sure if it's the second one. The code after the second loop works perfectly testing it on the page.

Comment: Sent! Thank you!

Comment: looking through it now.

Comment: Yes @chitown88 it was a mistake passing it to stack. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Jason!